# Shared authentication cookie for ASP.NET 4.X Apps still requires login on one of the apps

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have found a ton of information on how to share an authentication cookie between ASP.NET 4.X and ASP.NET CORE, but I am not finding any documentation on how to share between two 4.X apps. One of the apps is `ASP.NET 4.6.2` and the other is `ASP.NET 4.8`.

It's probably super simple but I would like some clarification on it.

In the `Startup.Auth.cs` of both apps, I have the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieName = "MySharedCookieName",
    CookieDomain = ".mydomain.com",
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120),
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
```

One of the apps is on `subdomain1.mydomain.com` and the other app is on `subdomain2.mydomain.com`.

When I log in at `subdomain1.mydomain.com` I can see the cookie get created and when I navigate to `subdomain2.mydomain.com` I can see the same cookie. However, I am still required to login on the second app.

Here is a screenshot of the cookie on the second app that still requires me to login:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `<machineKey>` setting in the `web.config` for both apps.

Since both apps are different, each one couldn't decrypt the other apps cookie which prevented the user from being logged in when switching apps.

Here is an example of the machineKey in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey
        validationKey="06023CE680E641825E7C06970C2653F5586F2796CA277E4DC9027E6996A3379D7EF1C4D14109C79123635017742DEB60FD3B05B7CDC185895AEE6808704B67AA"
        decryptionKey="65A8083F5E7B40873482F91E47CD92D14516670BE9D789BA4BCB3D7A96A3154F"
        validation="SHA1"
        decryption="AES">
    </machineKey>
</system.web>
```